# Unable to jump to source code when navigating the code maps

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am able to generate the code map for my solution but for some reason, I can't link the object on the map with the source code. For instance if I locate my cursor on the Coins object and double click or pressed F12 nothing happens and I get the message: "Cannot view content for: Coins". Thanks for any help.

[image]